# Is it right merge behavior?

Tags: mercurial

I have such branches tree: [image: branches tree]

And now I want merge from default branch (52 rev) to max.grigoriev.test branch (49 rev)

Here's 49 rev changes (I added test.css there):

[image: 49 rev]

Results after previous merge 51 rev (test.css was added)

[image]

But in next 52 rev I decided to delete test.css

[image]

And what I expect after merge 52 to 49 is to have a new php file(adtweaker_view.php) in my branch and test.css should be deleted. But mercurial just adds a new php file and doesn't remove test.css

[image: merged tree]

[image: merged result]

I don't understand why?

Comment: So you've got two branches. One added and then removed a file, and the other just added it. Are you sure you didn't get a conflict in the merge?

Comment: yes, I added a file in A branch, then I merged it + C branch to B branch, then removed the file in B branch and tried to merge B to A back and I just received changes from C branch(merged in B) and no conflict on added/removed file.

Comment: Changing something on both branches and taking it back on one can lead to very confusing behavior. I consider this a bug: http://mercurial.selenic.com/bts/issue1327

I'm not certain if this has/should have been fixed in the meantime; reading through the issue comments does not make that clear.

Comment: Your revision 51 isn't actually a merge -- it only has one parent (47). What were you expecting it to change?

Answer (score 0):

**test.css:**

1. The file is added in the yellow branch (rev 49).
2. In the blue branch, the file is first added (rev 51) and then removed (rev 52). The result is as if nothing happened in the blue branch.

Merging blue branch into yellow branch results in no change as nothing happened in the blue branch. Hence, your merge result of this file is correct.

**adtweaker_view.php:**

1. The file adtweaker_view.php is not added in any of the above revisions, so it can't be new as you say, can it?
2. The file is modified in the blue branch(rev 51).

Merging blue branch into yellow branch will modify the file as in (2). Hence, your merge result of this file is correct.

**adreplicator_view.php**

1. The file is only modified in the blue branch (rev 51)

The merge of blue branch into yellow branch should result in a modification of the file. Hence, your merge result is incorrect! It seems like your mercurial application forgot about the adreplicator_view.php modification (rev 51).